# merge 2 array and add a new item if key exists

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible to merge 2 arrays without overlapping the same keys ?

I want it to add a new item if a key already exists.

Like that

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(3,4,5,6);
merge $a and $b
```

desired result is

```
array(1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(3,4,5,6);
$c = array_merge($a,$b);
print_r($c);
```

[Working example here](http://codepad.org/g3EEqLiq)

This is the key phrase from the help :

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

So this will only work when you have numeric keys

Comment: can i use array_unshift for the same think but in order to prepend second array ?

Comment: @Ahmetvardar nope - you would have to loop the second array and unshift a key/value at a time - unshifting an array produces the following -> http://codepad.org/oViUCBel

Answer (score 5):

Try [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$result = array_merge($a, $b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `array_merge` for this purpose. But I want to point out that the contents of the arrays are the values of the arrays and not keys. In PHP **you cannot have duplicate keys**.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
$merged_array = array_merge($a, $b);
?>
```

Also exists function array_merge_recursive.